# Php tags converted to html

Tags: php, apache, html-entities

I have the following code:

```
<link href="<?=__CSS__?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

__ CSS __ is a constant related to the path of the styles folder but in the browser it's converted like this:

```
<link href="&lt;?=__CSS__?&gt;/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a configuration problem?How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution #1 : enable shorttags**

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

And restart your Apache server.

**Solution #2 : don't use it**

Change

```
<link href="<?=__CSS__?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="<?php echo __CSS__; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not change

```
<link href="<?=__CSS__?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To

```
<link href="<?php __CSS__?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It is, however personally i've witnessed issues with short tags in other code areas before, and was suggesting a way to solve the problem that will not cause future pain (e.g deploying to a different server)